# LINQ And Concurrency Question

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I am developing three applications that all share a common database.
I'm running into many different concurrency issues and was wondering if it is possible to prevent any other queries to execute when certain queries are running (in other words, locking the database so there won't be any concurrency issues).

Edit: I'm using LINQ to SQL

Comment: What database are you using, and what specific concurrency issues are you encountering? Most databases are extremely good at handling concurrency, when used appropriately.

Comment: What database are you using?  MySQL, PostGres, an in-memory array?  There should be some kind of locking available depending on what it is, but we can't answer unless we know what you're working with.

Comment: I'm using SQL.  The specific issue I'm having is when two users execute an update command at the same time.  Certain rows may be affected by one query, while others are affected by another.

Comment: If I can lock out the database while an update query runs, I wouldn't have this issue.

Comment: LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Entities?

Comment: LINQ to SQL is what I'm using

Comment: What kind of operations are running concurrently, that are causing trouble? Can you describe a bit more?? Right now, your question is too broad, not precise enough to really answer.....

Comment: I would be interested in knowing if something like this is possible: DB.Lock(); DB.SubmitChanges(); DB.Unlock();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always [use TransactionScope together with the appropriate locking hints](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/2d6fdb2e-e17e-4a4c-8da0-6968e60ef855) to lock people out. Now, the question is why you would want to do that...

...a better approach might be to do your own soft-locking mechanism, i.e. a table where you can insert a flag that a certain operation is under way and then have others check that table before doing something that could conflict with that operation.

Using DB locks for this should be a last resort.

See:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/2d6fdb2e-e17e-4a4c-8da0-6968e60ef855
...and...
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqtosql/thread/1b20c00d-bb53-4057-a336-79d962eb463f